# Explain N-poles and E-poles?

Tags: modeling

what is N-poles and E-pole?
I can not understand it.
And i read the some blogs they said to E-poles has 5 edges and N-poles has 3 edges.

  -

---

Answer (score 6):

This ,and more, is on the [Topology Guides](https://topologyguides.com/) site:

> E-poles or [**E**xtrude poles](http://3dgumshoe.com/general-3d-modeling-e-and-n-poles/)  are the most common pole type and consist of five edges intersecting at a single vertex. E-poles are most notorious for appearing when extruding faces on a mesh and for forming unwanted flat “corners” within the topology when edge loops meet or turn.  E-poles are also what form concave corners in hard surface models.

and

> N-poles or ["**N**ose" poles](http://3dgumshoe.com/general-3d-modeling-e-and-n-poles/) are vertices that consist of three intersecting edges. This type of pole is far less common, but often appearing around poles or inset parts of a mesh. In organic modeling, this pole is often known as the “nose” pole, since N-poles are often necessary for modeling the base of the nose. N-poles are also what form the corner of a cube or most other convex corners.

Comment: I'm trying to understand *why* these poles are prefixed with E and N letters. This is what makes them so hard to remember which one is which. Why not call them 3-poles and 5-poles? An N-pole to me, sounds like it should be the name for poles with 6 or more connected edges, so that i follows the same logic for the N-prefix used in N-gons for 5+ vert polygons.

Comment: I edited my answer and gave another link. Hope this explains the terms.